# Cannot import numpy in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was running some model in jupyter notebook, but my computer crashed all of a sudden. Once I restarted my computer, I was not able to import numpy in my jupyter notebook, and got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\miniconda3\envs\fraud_detection\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     21 try:
---> 22     from . import multiarray
     23 except ImportError as exc:

~\miniconda3\envs\fraud_detection\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py in <module>
     11 
---> 12 from . import overrides
     13 from . import _multiarray_umath

~\miniconda3\envs\fraud_detection\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in <module>
      6 
----> 7 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      8     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d4cdadb62aa7> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy

~\miniconda3\envs\fraud_detection\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138     from . import _distributor_init
    139 
--> 140     from . import core
    141     from .core import *
    142     from . import compat

~\miniconda3\envs\fraud_detection\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     46 """ % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1], sys.executable,
     47         __version__, exc)
---> 48     raise ImportError(msg)
     49 finally:
     50     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\miniconda3\envs\fraud_detection\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried deleting the whole anaconda and jupyter notebook, but it still did not work. Oddly, when I launched python in conda command shell I could successfully import numpy. Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I have the same problem with python 3.8.8 numpy 1.20.1